# What function would I need to use to block other apps/websites in my app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am designing my second android app. I would like to know if there is a function that blocks an app. For example when the button is on, that app cannot be used. Is it possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will need to add more information to your question, as it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: It is a study app - In the app, other applications can be blocked so no time is wasted.

Comment: I'm thinking that what you may want to do is create a custom launcher instead of just a normal app.

Comment: So you waste your time developing an app to stop you wasting your time while you should be studying.  How ironic ;-)

Comment: I generally don't make comments like this but I think the app would be useless, when I want to concentrate I close my internet browser, but there is nothing stopping me from re-opening it again, just as there is nothing stopping your users from unblocking an app that they just blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for a second app this is bit adventurous, but i will give you hints anyways !

Create a custom android launcher which will have two modes. Study mode and play mode. In study mode allow all the apps.and in the child mode allow on specified apps to be launched. There are multiple opensource launcher samples for you to start.

For websites the approach is the same, write a custom webview which will allow the same as above. Although having root + system access will make this even easier but if not you are stuck with writing your own webview implementation.

look at some of similar apps in the google play which can given you some insights !